# Time Complexity of a loop where n is given

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity

I am new to time complexities and wanted to know if we are given a for loop where n is given, is the time complexity still O(n)?
For example:

```
for (i = 0, i<5, i++){ do something
```

Would this time complexity be O(1) because of 5*O(1) or would it still be O(n)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Let's assume that `something` takes constant time.)

This:

```
for (i = 0, i<n, i++){ do something }
```

is O(n).

This:

```
for (i = 0, i<k, i++){ do something }
```

is O(k). Its run-time does not depend on `n`.

This:

```
for (i = 0, i<5, i++){ do something }
```

is O(1). That is, constant.